Calculation of special subsets in high-dimensional binary matrices
I need to solve a rather specific problem related to binary matrices. The task is to count the number of specific "combinations", where "combination" means the following:
this is an non-empty set of columns of the original matrix and some set of values (of the corresponding dimension) such that:

the submatrix formed by the columns does not have these values in its rows
any non-empty subset of selected columns (from 1.) should have a row which contains a subset of values of corresponding dimension (from 1.)

The definition may seem confusing, so I will give an example of an explicit calculation and hope everything will become clear:
$$A = [a_1a_2a_3a_4] = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

let's start with the dimension $1$:

$$a_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    1 \\
    0
\end{bmatrix}$$
There are both $0$ and $1$ in the column, so it will not be possible to select a value to meet the required condition.
The same is true for columns $a_2$, $a_3$, $a_4$.

Now the pairs of columns

$$a_1a_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0\\
    1 & 1\\
    0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
It can be seen that there are no value of $10$ and $01$ in the rows of this matrix. And both of these values satisfy the second condition: the first component is in the first column of the matrix, the second component is in the second column of the matrix. Total: +2 to the counter of combinations
$$a_1a_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    1 & 0\\
    0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
In this case, the value $11$ is suitable.
Also for $a_1a_4$ the value $11$ is suitable, for $a_2a_3$: $11$, for $a_2a_4$: $11$, for $a_3a_4$: $11$
So, there are $7$ combinations of columns and values on this step.

Now three columns

$$A^{'} = a_1a_3a_4 = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
Let's look at value $000$. Subsets of this value are $*00$, $0*0$ and $00*$. And first is located in $A^{'}_{21}A{'}_{22}$, second can be found in $A^{'}_{11}A^{'}_{13}$, third is $A^{'}_{31}A{'}_{32}$. It means that columns $a_1a_3a_4 $ value $000$ are satisfied all requirements.
Also submatrix $a_2a_3a_4$ also gives this value $000$.
We can look at all the other samples of $3$ columns from matrix $A$ and all possible values, but in this case nothing else will give us the combination we need.
That is, at this step we will add $2$ more combinations (columns and values).

Now full matrix $A$

We can see that all possible variants of string values, such that they are not in the matrix (e.g. $0000$, $0100$, $1000$, $0011$ and so on), do not satisfy the second verification condition.
For example, let's look at $0000$. Subsets of this value are $000*$, $00*0$, $0*00$ and $*000$. They all should be found in our submatrix (here the submatrix is a full matrix). Fist subset $000*$ can be found in third row: $A_{31}A_{32}A_{33}$, second subset can be found in a first row: $A_{11}A_{12}A_{14}$, but for the third subset $0*00$, we cannot find a match in the submatrix $A$.
The result for this example is $9$ combinations (set of columns and values)
Problem
I need to solve this problem numerically, that is, to find the number of combinations for any matrix (including large ones, for example, $50$ columns). My solution involves a complete iteration of combinations (in fact, as in the example I described above, only in a general way), I use bitwise operations to check only masks for values and subsets of columns, and I also use caching, since the problem, for example, for $13$ columns is reduced to $13$ problems for $12$ columns and so on. This allows me not to count everything over again every time, but starting from small dimensions to reduce the problem to an already solved one.
However, I reach the limit very quickly due to the "combinatorial explosion", I cannot count and store combinations of a matrix with $20$ columns (I do this in python).
It seems to me that my solution method has obvious limitations, perhaps calculations can be optimized somehow, but I don't understand how. Probably, the solution to this problem is implied through other techniques.
I would be very grateful if you could help me with general advises, some tricks from linear algebra, combinatorics, etc. that would be useful in solving this problem.

I'm pretty confused by the conditions. If $A\in M_{m,n}({0,1})$ is the original matrix, $M\in M_{m,k}({0,1})$ is the submatrix of the chosen columns, and $S\subseteq {0,1}^k$ is the set of values, do you want any subset of columns from $M$ to have a row containing an element of $S$? Does every value of $S$ have to have the same length? From what I understand of the example, this isn't the case, and I'm understanding something wrong. The first condition is saying $M$ should not have values of $S$ in its rows, right?

If I understood your question right then I can propose the following approach. For any natural number $k$ put $[k]=\{1,\dots,k\}$. Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ binary matrix. Each subset of columns of $A$ can be encoded by a subset $S$ of $[n]$ (or an $1\times n$ binary vector). So we have to consider each such subset $S$. Given $S$, let $k=|S|$, and $A_S$ be a $m\times k$ matrix, whose columns are the columns of the matrix $A$ whose numbers belong to $S$. For each natural $i\le m$ and $j\le k$ let $A_{S,i,j}$ be the $i$th row of the matrix $A_S$ with the $j$th element inverted. Let $\mathcal A_S$ be the set of rows from $\bigcap_{j=1}^k \bigcup_{i=1}^m A_{S,i,j}$, which are not rows of $A_S$. The combinations corresponding to the set $S$ are exactly from $\mathcal A_S$, so $S$ adds to the counter of combinations exactly $|\mathcal A_S|$.

But it seems that (at least, usually) there are not so many combinations. Then I expect that the following inductive construction of the family $\mathcal C$ of combinations will work much faster. The family $\mathcal C$ is contained in a family $\mathcal C^*$ of extended combinations, whose members are maps from subsets of $[n]$ to $\{0,1\}$.
Initially $\mathcal C$ is empty and $\mathcal C^*$ consists of the empty function, that is, the function from the empty set, and the column counter $j$ is $0$. Suppose that we already
constructed the families $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal C^*$ at a step $j<n$. At the step $j+1$ we check all members of $\mathcal C^*\setminus \mathcal C$. Let a checked member be a map $f$ from a set $S\subset [j]$. Let $S'=S\cup\{j+1\}$. There are two possible extensions of $f$ to $S'$. For each such extension $f'$ we check whether for each $j'\in S$ there exists $r\in [m]$ such that for each $j''\in S'\setminus \{j'\}$ we have $f'(j'')=A_{r,j''}$. If this condition holds then we add $f'$ to $\mathcal C^*$. Moreover, if there exists no $r\in [m]$ such that for each $j''\in S'$ we have $f'(j'')=A_{r,j''}$ then we add $f'$ also to $\mathcal C$. The required number of combination is the size of the family $\mathcal C$ after the last, $n$th, step.
